# Pantone TCX to Coated conversion

Tags: color-conversion, resource-recommendations, pantone

I need to convert some fabric colors to ink colors for screen printing. In the past I would use Pantone's X-Ref web utility but they've discontinued it. The only option appears to be paid a premium subscription to Pantone Connect.

Does anyone know of an alternative, free online resource for TCX-to-Coated conversions?

Failing that, would there be any Pantone Connect subscribers willing to convert 3 swatches for me please?

The colors I need to convert are:

PANTONE 19-0509 TCX

PANTONE 19-0516 TCX

PANTONE 19-4015 TCX

Thank you!

Comment: Although I totally sympathize with your frustration and am completely puzzled by how it's good business for Pantone to prevent designers from using their inks, I don't think it's fitting to ask people to convert colors for you on this site. It is in essence to ask for "free work".

Comment: Fair point!
I was really hoping someone could recommend a free online resource for conversions. The help request was a hail mary in case a friendly fellow designer could spare the 30 seconds it would take to convert them.

Comment: (Welcome to the site btw. ) It's not the 30 seconds. If I had access to Pantone Connect, I wouldn't mind finding those 3 inks for you right now. It's just a principle we need to uphold to prevent being flooded with requests ruining the site. (If you stick around and get 20 reputation points you'll get access to the chat where such a request would be more appropriate imo.)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Brand new here so I'm still learning the ropes. I appreciate your point.

Comment: Take a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Pantone Connect is only £5.99 per month (I can't access the USD price), there's also a free trial, and they also say you can cancel any time. If it was me, I'd pay for the month, then cancel.

As for doing it for free and accurately - there may be no direct PMS equivalent, but if near enough will do then you could sample the hex colour from the swatch on the Pantone site using a colour picker tool - I used ShareX for this. Seems rather silly that they blur it out, when you can sample it anyway.

[image]

Then you could do a search on google "#36362d to Pantone PMS"

Should get you some results

For example: https://icolorpalette.com/color/36362D

And in fact I notice that particular site actually allows you to search using the TCX number anyway, so you could skip the sampling step altogether.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go!
As for the Adobe Connect trial - the trial version doesn't allow users to convert colors.

Comment: @Fullbleed - well that's a bit sh*t, so you can't even try out the main feature to evaluate it, to check if it's worth buying!!!!

Comment: I was incorrect. Free account won't allow you to do any conversions (aka "Cross References"), but the free trial of the Premium account will allow for cross referencing. $60 a year to convert colors is giant rip off though. I'll be cancelling well before my 30 days are up.

Answer (score 0):

due to the vast number in views, I would suggest this issue is a problem and that Pantone is the one being greedy